# Retrieving elements that are occurring after adding a fixed number from a start element in a vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have,

```
temp <- c(94, 95, 108, 110, 119, 122, 130, 137, 143, 149, 151)
```

and I need to get all the elements that is occurring after adding multiples of 7 to the starting element (94).

So, one should get something like below

```
94, 108, 122, 143
```

I tried something like below:

```
b <- temp[seq(1, length(temp), 7)]
94 137
```

which is actually incorrect since it generates sequence of numbers that occurs after 7th place in the list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you get 137 and 151? After adding 7's in 94 we get 136 and 150 actually.

Comment: Basically, if you add 7 to the starting element which is 94..then you will get the following - 94 101 108 115 122 129 137 144 151 158 165..but in **temp** we have 137 and 151 so we need to keep them in the final result.

Comment: No you get `94 101 108 115 122 129 136 143 150`. `129 + 7` gives `136`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to check that the modulo after subtracting the initial value equals zero:

```
temp[(temp - 94) %% 7 == 0]
#[1]  94 108 122 143
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `intersect` after generating the sequence

```
intersect(seq(temp[1], max(temp), by = 7), temp)
#[1]  94 108 122 143
```